# Is it possible to create txt sitemaps index file?

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap

I am creating sitemaps using Google Search Console and we are exploring an option of [creating txt sitemaps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en&ref_topic=4581190). 
There are many sitemaps so using [a sitemaps index file](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?visit_id=637207391001025216-4215402076&rd=1) is basically a requirement but I didn't find the way of doing that in the sitemap protocol and [Google SCH](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=en&ref_topic=4581190&visit_id=637207391001025216-4215402076&rd=1).

I tried building txt sitemaps index file akin to the txt sitemaps:

```
url_to_first_sitemap
url_to_second_sitemap
```

but Google SC treats this file as a sitemap and doesn't detect the linked sitemap file and its urls.

Is it possible to create txt sitemaps index file?

Comment: How many of them do you have?  If it isn't too many, one solution could be just to list each txt file in robots.txt individually

Comment: I don't know if it would work, but another thing to try might be an XML sitemap index that points to the individual text sitemaps.

Comment: Hard to tell, the data which is used to create links is dynamic, in the range from 400 to >1000. Speaking of xml sitemap index file, I am aware of this possibility: having xml index to refer the sitemaps though I didn't test it yet and don't know if it'll work.

Comment: Even 400 sitemap links it too many to put in robots.txt.   If you do end up testing the XML index, please report here whether or not it works.  Hopefully somebody here has some experience they can share with you, but I don't guarantee it.

Comment: Usualy use XML format to validate sitemaps in search console. For example: `http://www.example.com/sitemaps.xml`